# Excel vba workbooks.open event giving a runtime error 1004 - The Disk Is Full

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting a 1004 disk is full error when I try and open a file using:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=inputfolder & "\" & inputfile, ReadOnly:=True
```

I have also tried this with the filepath and name hard-coded, with the same result. Does anyone have any ideas as to the cause?

Comment: Try to check if it works with hard-coded full path to file. If it does, then check your variables. Regards,

Comment: Still does it I'm afraid.

Comment: Does this error occur with every file you try, or just one?

Comment: I don't think this is a VBA issue - more an Excel one, as I'm now getting the same message when I try and open a workbook manually (it eventually opens but with an error - lost visual basic project)........

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this error while trying to open from a shared location, it was caused by not having write permissions on the folder.

If this is the case, try running the same code but with workbooks saved locally on your PC.

Answer (score 1):

First, try to check if it works with hard-coded full path to file, like (for example):

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\\somedir\somefile.xls", ReadOnly:=True
```

If it does, then check your variables to make sure they point to right location. If the error persists, try to open ANY Excel file in that particular folder (just for test purpose, put an empty File `test.xls`). If it works on that test file, then your target file is either corrupted, or you do not have permissions to open it; in case it fails again, then you probably do not have permissions on that folder.

Regards,

Comment: Tried this originally :-(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. In my case the problem was the file extension. I used ".xls" and not ".xlsx" maybe it is the same issue with your path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a shared location. Same times the issue is that the data-base file is corrupted by using one of de diferent version of the excel. 
To solve it, we had just opened the data-base file, recovering the source with the excel itself automaticly, and close it.